# SQLite query with multiple filters

Tags: android, sqlite, args

I've an cursor that fills up my ListView in Android.

My code of cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query("ProductosTratamientos", null,
            "codigoproducto <> '70027, 70029, 70024'", null, null, null, null);
```

It is not working. It continues filling the list with these values: 70027, 70029, 70024.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `<>`, you need to use `NOT IN` which offers look-up with in a set of values. So try changing your query to something like:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query("ProductosTratamientos", null,
       "codigoproducto NOT IN (70027, 70029, 70024)", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query("ProductosTratamientos", null,
            "codigoproducto <> ? AND codigoproducto <> ? AND codigoproducto <> ?',
            new String[]{"70027", "70029", "70024"},
            null, null, null);
```